# How does a bean, with @Autowired, gets its dependency if the dependency's interface does not exist in the container

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am learning Spring framework and I am stuck now about dependency injection.

In this question, I am asking about Java Configuration.

I know @Autowired annotation automatically wires the dependency and the bean by referencing a qualified implementation class of the declared interface.

However, I do not know how the function, `transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)`, gets its `SessionFactory` argument instance when there is no bean returns `SessionFactory` in my studying code.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

    // create session factorys
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    // set the properties
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(securityDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hiberante.packagesToScan"));
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    // setup transaction manager based on session factory
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return txManager;
}
```

I assume that the `transactionManager()` gets its argument from `sessionFactory()`. But `sessionFactory()` does not return `SessionFactory`  instance, it returns `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. The `LocalSessionFactoryBean` does not implement `SessionFactory` either, it implements `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`.

In this case, doesn't `transactionManager()` suppose to use argument type `LocalSessionFactoryBean` or `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>` instead of having `SessionFactory`? Like: `transactionManager(FactoryBean<SessionFactory> sessionFactory)`

I am confused with how `transactionManager()` gets its dependency.

Thank you,

Comment: `FactoryBeans` are special cases in Spring DI, `NB: A bean that implements this interface cannot be used as a normal bean. A FactoryBean is defined in a bean style, but the object exposed for bean references (getObject()) is always the object that it creates.`

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding it right you are telling spring to create session factory for you using the configurations provided via LocalSessionFactoryBean, [see details here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html), it creates hibernate session factory for you and auto wire it. Actually its Spring frameworks common practice to save developer work here by letting you create session factory with minimum code.